# Problema com acentuação em um site

Tags: html

Em um site que desenvolvi, tenho o seguinte texto:
*A linha depilação da...*, esse texto abre perfeitamente no Windows, em qualquer navegador.
Já, no Mac, aparece o texto da seguinte forma: *A linha de depilac,a~o*.

O que pode ser isso?

A codificação do site está assim:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: Isso ocorre em qual navegador?

Comment: Cara, no Mac eu conferi no Google Chrome, porém no Chrome do Windows está Ok.

Comment: Acredito que seja no safari...

Comment: No Safari do Windows está Ok.

Comment: Você já incluiu a declaração `<meta>` identificando o charset. Mas os **arquivos** HTML estão neste padrão (UTF-8)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para poder escrever depilação e aparecer tal como escreve com a acentuação tem que alterar a codificação para:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=8859-1" />
```

Caso contrario terá que escrever `Depila&ccedil;&atilde;o` para aparecer Depilação.

Comment: Olá. Esse texto é gerenciável, o nosso sistema já faz isso automaticamente. Ou seja, se fosse isso, ele daria problema no Windows também.

Comment: Não percebi a sua resposta

Comment: Eu não preciso informar o charset, o nosso gerenciador de conteúdo já faz isso automaticamente.

Comment: Assim o problema não é da codificação mas do browser.

Comment: Tem como forçar a codificação do browser?

Comment: Tem que pensar que quem vai usar o site não terá a fonte do browser alterada para ler a sua pagina caso o charset esteja bem configura para o que o vosso gerenciador debita, um conselho já tive um problema parecido com esse e a questão estava nas extensões que tinha bloqueado sem querer e resolvi com uma desinstação completa.

Comment: Já agora qual foi a solução adoptada? A alteração do `charset` ou a desinstalação.

Comment: Cara, isso está na minha fila de bugs, só vou voltar pra ele semana que vem ahahah. Valeu :P

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza um HTMLEnconde:

`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myString);`

Esse código seria para uma aplicação .NET, mas você também pode utilizar jQuery para resolver isso:

`$('#campo').text(value).html();`

Answer (score 0):

Duas possíveis soluções:

1) Aparemente pode ser um problema de fontes do Mac.
Abra o Universal Type Client, pode ser que tenha 2 versões da fonte Arial em conflito.

Selecione a copia universal da fonte Arial e a desative.

2) Alterar a codificação nas configurações do Chrome
Ferramentas (Tools) > Codificação (Encoding) e selecione a opção Detecção Automática (Auto-detect).

Comment: Pode ser isso cara. Muito estranho que isso está acontecendo só com esse site. Sendo que sempre uso as mesmas configurações.

Comment: No Mac, além do Chrome, você tentou com outro navegador? deu certo?